# how to increase the jsch buffer size?

Tags: jsch

I am using jsch for sftp file transfer. When I send file using sftp command by setting the buffer size 512 (-B option ) sftp B 512 [sftp server name] and invoking put command, I can transfer files in 8.0MBPS. (The regular speed is 3.0MBPS).

When I do the same file transfer using jsch api in java, I get only 2.6MBPS. Is there any option to increase the buffer size in jsch or improve the speed of jsch?

Here is my code...

```
Channel channel = null;
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
log("preparing the host information for sftp.");
try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
    session.setPassword(password);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    System.out.println("Host connected.");
    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    log("sftp channel opened and connected.");
    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
    File f = new File(fileName);
    channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
    log("File transferred successfully to host.");
} catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println("Exception found while transfer the response.");
     ex.printStackTrace();
} finally{

    channelSftp.exit();
    log("sftp Channel exited.");
    channel.disconnect();
    log("Channel disconnected.");
    session.disconnect();
    log("Host Session disconnected.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the newer version of Jsch (1.50), it became faster downloading.

Answer (score 0):

It may work but I am not sure. I saw it somewhere in jsch code base.
You can try it out:

```
getSession().setConfig("max_input_buffer_size", "increased_size");
```